# binary array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, binary

if i have an initial array A of twenty numbers in the order 1 to 20,

```
 A = [1,2,3,4,5,...,20]
```

and have another random array B:

```
  B = [1, 15, 3, 20, 7]
```

and want to output a column vector C of the form

```
  C = [1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1]
```

Note that C has a 1 at the indices at which B has a value.

I have tried the following:

```
n=20;
C = zeros(n, 1);
for i=1:length(B)
   C(B(i))=1;
end
```

Comment: What `A` has got to do with anything?

Answer (score 2):

in a one-liner:

```
full(sparse(B,1,1,max(B),1))
```

and you could also drop the [full](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/full.html) function, most matlab matrix operation can deal with sparse matrices. But of course it depends on what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Another one-liner:

```
C = accumarray(B(:), 1, [], @(x)1)
```

Comment: Wrap it in `logical()` in case there are non-unique values in `B`.

Comment: @Simon: good catch, thank you. I solved it a slightly different way (to keep the result of type `double`).

Comment: +1: accumarray is actually specifically made just for these kind of things, why didn't I think of that :p

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vectorized solution:

Firstly, initialize `C`

```
   C = zeros( max(B),1);
```

Then use array indexing:

```
   C(B) = 1;
```